# Left join on Python

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two DataFrames that looks like this (Note: I am still a beginner and trying to learn joins better)

```
xx = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[13, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

yy = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3,5], [4, 5, 6,5], [7, 8, 9,5]]),
                   columns=['aa', 'bb', 'cc','dd'])
```

I want to preform a left join so that I have a final table that looks like this

```
aa bb cc dd
4  5  6  6
7  8  9  5
```

I have come up with this so far

```
zz = pd.merge(yy,xx, how = 'left', left_on= ['aa','bb'], right_on=['a','b'])
```

But this gives me the incorrect output which is

[image]

Can you please help me with what correction I need to make in order to get the desired output?

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you want a `left join` not an `inner join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expected output, you have to do an `inner join` not a `left join`. Also to join `pandas DataFrames` the columns must have common columns. So I've set the columns of `xx` to that in `yy`

```
>>>xx.columns=['aa','bb','cc']
>>>pd.merge(yy,xx,how='inner',on=['aa','bb','cc'])
   aa  bb  cc  dd
0   4   5   6   5
1   7   8   9   5
```

And this would be the output of left join of `yy` with `xx`:

```
>>>pd.merge(yy,xx,how='left',on=['aa','bb','cc'])
   aa  bb  cc  dd
0   1   2   3   5
1   4   5   6   5
2   7   8   9   5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the dataframes with equal column headers so another dataframe can be created by changing the column header before merging:

```
zz = pd.merge(xx.rename(columns={"a": "aa", "b": "bb","c":"cc"}),yy)
zz
```

[image]